# For each sets below determine if it is bounded above, bounded below, or both. If it is bounded above (below) find the supremum (infimum).

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $\big\{\frac{3n}{n+4}$: $n \in \mathbb{N}\big\}$. We have to use $\varepsilon$. For $\inf(A)= \frac{3}{5}$

$$\frac{3n}{n+4} > \frac{3n}{n+4n}=\frac{3n}{5n}=\frac{3}{5}.$$

For $\sup(A)$ we have to show $n-\varepsilon$. We know $$\frac{3n}{n+4}= 3-\frac{12}{n+4}.$$
We assume $\varepsilon < \frac{12}{n+4}$.

I dont know how to finish this proof.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are doing so here is my solution:

By definition the $\sup$ is the LEAST upper bound and similarly, the $\inf$ is the LARGEST lower bound for the set.

In your case, the set is a monotonic sequence - it is easily seen that $\frac{3n}{n+4}\leq \frac{3(n+1)}{n+5}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Hence, the infimum is $\frac{3}{5}$ since it is not-bigger than any of the numbers and it is in the set itself so the $\inf$ can't be bigger than it

As for the supremum - since the sequence tends to $3$ (try to show it using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument or as in your work, say that $\frac{12}{n+4}$ converges to $0$ and use algebra of limits) and is monotonic increasing, a reasonable guess should be that $3$ indeed is the supremum. This is actually the case and you can show it using the convergence of the sequence and the fact, the supremum is the least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your convention is $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Well, with your first steps you are proving that $\frac{3}{5}$ is a lower bound, not exactly the infimum. In order to prove the latter, you can observe that $$\frac{3}{5} = \frac{3\cdot1}{1+4}$$
so it corresponds to $n=1$. This shows $\frac{3}{5}$ is the minimum of your set, not only the infimum.

If you want to prove that $3$ is an upper bound, then your observation looks ok. To prove that it is the supremum, you should show now that for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$3-\varepsilon < \frac{3n}{n+4}. $$
This gives $n > \frac{12-4\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$ and you can conclude that $3$ is the supremum.

Comment: How can you conclude it is the sup(A)?

Comment: Because I can always find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > \frac{12-4\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$. It is enough to take, for example, the least number greater than $\frac{12}{\varepsilon}$.